# Unable to upload file in Spring Boot App - NoSuchFileException

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

I have tried to upload an image to the server but got this error:
`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: assets\images\product\curry chicken.jfif`

Typescript code:

```
onFileChanged(event){
      if(!event.target.files[0] || event.target.files[0].length == 0){
        this.message = "You must select an image!";
        return;
      }
      const file: File = event.target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        this.uploadImage(file);
      }
}


uploadImage(file: File) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    this.http.post('/admin/menu/add/upload', formData).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully', response);
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error('Error uploading file', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Java Code:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/menu/add/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        // Check if the file is empty
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return "File is empty";
        }
        try {
            // Save the file to the specified location
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(uploadPath + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            return "File uploaded successfully";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error uploading file";
        }
    }
```

Is that I set the wrong path in application.properties?
The error is at java or typescript as I checked the console.log, there is not error except the error returned by controller.